# android boofcv ip camera manipulation using videoview

Tags: android, ip-camera, boofcv

I have successfully stream ip camera on an android phone using rtsp using this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        VideoView video= (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);

        String viewSource = "rtsp://192.168.1.........";

        video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(viewSource));
        video.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        video.requestFocus();
        video.start();

    }

}
```

My question is that is it possible to manipulate videoview on android using boofcv which is using ip camera? Because on boofcv samples it is using a built in camera on android phone. If someone is kind here can help me please.

Comment: I would very much like to know that...