# Boofcv record from RTSP link

Tags: java, boofcv

*Current status*

I have successfully recording videos from **RTSP** with the help of javacv which is not purely on java.

*Problem*

Create pure java application. Found [boofcv](http://boofcv.org/) which is completely java. Have found [example for recording in android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212057/android-boofcv-ip-camera-manipulation-using-videoview). My program is not in android its should run in windows and linux. Need to record many camera at the same time.

*Objective.*

Motion detection which is implemented in javacv just need to port into a independent java program.

*Extra information*

Using rtsp to get video from cameras.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know anything about RTSP, but if you can get a BufferedImage from it it should be easy to convert into a BoofCV image using ConvertBufferedImage.  Alternatively the BoofCV image format is very simple.

Comment: Just noticed how ancient this question is... Hope you found a solution!